# Make http request using ws async in java

Tags: java

Here is my code trying to make a request and capture the response using async Java

```
public void refresh() {
    WSRequest complexRequest = ws.url("https://data-in.bookmyshow.com/index.bms?cc=&cmd=GETEVENTLIST"
            + "&dt=&et=MT&f=json&lg=77.617062&lt=12.973863&rc=&sr=&t=67x1xa33b4x422b361ba")
            .setHeader("Cookie", "_ga=GA1.2.502429537.1474554084; __cfduid=d66fdddeb030179b64125f9bdec10c"
                    + "0621474454876").setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .setHeader("Accept", "*/*").setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            .setHeader("User-Agent", "BookMyShow/3.2.6 (iPhone; iOS 10.0.1; Scale/2.00)");
    CompletionStage<JsonNode> jsonPromise = complexRequest.get().thenApply(WSResponse::asJson);
    jsonPromise.thenApply(res-> {System.out.println(res);});
}
```

I am unable to compile the code and get following error

```
[error] /Users/vangapellisanthosh/Development/bot/app/services/BookMyShow.java:41: method thenApply in interface java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<T> cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: java.util.function.Function<? super com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,? extends U>
[error]   found: (res)->{ S[...]s); }
[error]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
[error]     (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
[error]       missing return value)
[error]         jsonPromise.thenApply(res-> {System.out.println(res);});
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/vangapellisanthosh/Development/bot/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/vangapellisanthosh/Development/bot/app/services/BookMyShow.java:41: method thenApply in interface java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<T> cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: java.util.function.Function<? super com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,? extends U>
[error]   found: (res)->{ S[...]s); }
[error]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
[error]     (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
[error]       missing return value)
[error]         jsonPromise.thenApply(res-> {System.out.println(res);});
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application - 

! @71ffp4ogk - Internal server error, for (GET) [/count] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[method thenApply in interface java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,? extends U>
  found: (res)->{ S[...]s); }
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      missing return value)]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
```

What is the mistake I am making how do I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the response back as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) like:

```
jsonPromise.thenApply(res-> {
                        System.out.println(res);
                        return ok(render("application/json", res);});
```